# How to handle potential ambiguity when one-hot encoding?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-encoding, feature-engineering

Let's say I have two categorical features: Movie, Director. I one-hot encode both the Movie and Director features for use in a linear regression model.

The problem is that two or more movies may be directed by the same director. i.e. a particular director's bit may be on for two or more different movies. Would this cause any problem during training?

Comment: Why would this cause a problem? They are separate features and can coincide.

Comment: Would combining movie and director into one feature and one-hot encoding that be a better option?

Comment: I don't understand why you think it would be a problem, can you explain? In general I would say no, but it depends on your model/data. Do you want to estimate separate effects for movie and director? More information on the type of model you want to fit might help.

Answer (score 0):

No this will not be a problem.  This is the reason that you have two features.  If you want one "movie-director" feature combine the columns.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se].
Thank you for your answer.
Can you please [edit] you answer to expand it? It will be more helpful for the original poster and for people searching in this site.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[answer], on 
[formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).